# How to get the line numbers of a method and its body by using our own eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created an eclipse plugin where the user right clicks the method in the package explorer. It will generate a file with the method body. Currently my output is

```
public int add(int x,int y){
 int z=x+y;
 return z;
}
```

I am using `SourceMethod` for getting the method content. The code is as follows.

```
 public void methodGenerator(SourceMethod methodname){
     String methodcontent=methodname.getSource();
     filegenerator = new FileWriter(FilePath);
     writer = new BufferedWriter(filegenerator);
     writer.write(methodcontent);
 }
```

Here I am using `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceMethod` to get the method content. Now i need to get the line numbers. So how I can get the line numbers of the method ?

I have gone through [How to get the line number of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834887/how-to-get-the-line-number-of-a-method) here we can get only the starting line no. My requirement is the generated file content should be as follows:

```
14.public int add(int x,int y){
15. int z=x+y;
16. return z;
17.}
```

Please give me some suggestions. Am very much in need of this logic. Please help me out!

Comment: If you have the number of the first line, can't you just split the `methodcontent` string into lines and write the line number + line in a loop?

Comment: @Keppil - This method extracts the method data completely. Are there any another logic or methods to extract the data along with the line numbers, as using the loop increases the overhead and degrades the application performance.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that the performance degradation is negligible.

Comment: @Keppil - Thanks for your valuable suggestion.but when i go for a java file it may have several methods. so is there is any way to fetch the line numbers directly. because i may need it for other functionalities too.

Comment: `SourceMethod` is an **internal** class and you should not be using it, it may be changed without warning [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html). Use an interface such as `IMethod` which is part of the official API.

Comment: Once you have access to IMethod, you can get the compilation unit using `iMethod.getCompilationUnit();` and find the line number. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126857/eclipse-astnode-to-source-code-line-number/